# How does the computer get the output in the following code?

Tags: python

I cannot understand how the code gets the final result. Can someone explain in a detailed manner as to how python is interpreting and executing this?

```
counts = [5, 2, 5, 2, 2]
for x_count in counts:
    output=""
    for count in range(x_count):
        output+="x"
    print(output)`
```

Results:

```
 xxxxx 
 xx
 xxxxx
 xx
 xx
```

I cannot understand the code. Why was for count in range(x_count) used and output +=x should result in "5+x" instead of "xxxxx"? Generally to get "XXXXX" we should use print (5*"x"), how does using + give me the same output?

How does the range function help here?

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: What are you expecting by this?

Comment: It's outputting the same number of `x` characters as the number in your array. Did you expect something else?

Comment: I cannot understand the code. Why was for count in range(x_count) used and output +=x should result in "5+x" instead of "xxxxx"?

Comment: The code is very simple. Perhaps you should do some more Python courses. Unfortunately SO is not the place to teach a programming language basics.

Comment: The output +="x" means that  evrey time uou will loop over counts you will concatinate an x to the result

Comment: Where would `5+x` come from? Both `output` and `"x"` are strings. Start your Python and enter `output = ""; output += "x"; print(output); output += "x"; print(output); output += "x"; print(output)` and think about what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

[Colab link for the code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CgJS6r0AGvLu21qewRiM_CgxJ0VzhTj2)

I commented the code for your understanding.

```
counts = [5, 2, 5, 2, 2] # Counts of X
for x_count in counts: # For every count value
    output="" # Output holds bunch of X 
    # output is reset at every iteration
    for count in range(x_count):
        output+="x" # Populate output with X values for each count
        # + and += concats strings
    print(output) # print output
```

A similar approach:

```
counts = [5, 2, 5, 2, 2]
outputs = ["".join(['x'] * count) for count in counts]
for output in outputs:
  print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
counts = [5, 2, 5, 2, 2]                    # counts
for x_count in counts:                      # will loop over each element in count
    output=""                               # variable to hold xs
    for count in range(x_count):            # will loop x_count times
        output+="x"                         # 'x' will be appended to output variable
    print(output)                           # output will be printed
```

Comment: the range(x-count) should give me the following values for every count (0,1,2,3,4,0,1....) so shouldnt the output be x xx xxx xxxx x ....... why am i getting xxxxx xx xxxxx xx xx? does the for loop count the range value and then use the count to give me the output?

Comment: That is because you're printing output AFTER the loop ends. If you indent your print statement ie  `print(output)` (add some space before it). It will give you x xx xxx xxxx x .......

Answer (score 0):

your orignal list

```
counts = [5, 2, 5, 2, 2]

for count in counts:
```

this means for value in counts ie it select first element then second , then third
so on till the last element ie. it select 5 first ,2 next and so on

```
original = '' # intialise the element
```

this will create a string element having value `''` ,

```
for value in range(count):
```

range(count) give value in range `[0,count)` ie a list of numbers from 0 inclusive to 
count (exclusive)

so `for value in [0,1...count]`

so it will select value form list  first element then second so on

no for each value you are adding `x` to `original` so `for` loop will run count 
time and add `x` to `original`

```
print(orignal)
```

will print the value of origanl till now

Comment: for value in [0,1...count] shouldnt the outpt be therefore x xx xxx xxxx      x  xx and so on(since we are using a range function) . Why am i getting xxxxx xx xxxxx xx xx. Please elaborate

Comment: i already explained how your code work, if you want output like you want, just instead of inner loop write `output = count * 'x'  print(output) `

Comment: I have tried using the simpler way like you mentioned but I wanted to understand how it can be done using nested loops, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: @NavneetKothari maybe taking a course in python is  a good start

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [5,2,5,2,2]
for x_count in numbers:
     output = ''
     for count in range(x_count):
         output += 'x'
     print(output)
```

The first 'for' is receiving the value of 'numbers' in 'x_count', the 'output' is created.
In the second 'for' that will take the amount of 'numbers' that was inserted in the 'x_count' variable and through the 'output', which is initially empty and is reset after each interaction, the x will be incremented according to the amount of 'range(x_count)' which in position 0 is equal to 5, and so on until this result is output-->

```
xxxxx
xx
xxxxx
xx
xx
```